# Table overflow working in Chrome and IE but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-table, screen

I am trying to get a layout that always takes up the entire screen, no more, no less.  The layout has a header row, a 200px wide left bar (scrollable), and a scrollable content area.

This works in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the scroll bars never show nor work.  Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#viewTable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#header {
    height: 72px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#leftcol {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#menu {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#rightcol {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<table id="viewTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" id="header">
            Header
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="leftcol">
            <div id="menu">
                0<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                100<br/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="rightcol">
            <div id="content">
                0<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                100<br/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
hi
</html>
```

I would have preferred to use CSS, but could not find any way to do it.

The hi should no show, it is simply there to verify it does not.

Comment: first thing I notice: never make layouts using tables, they're designed for tabular data only.

Comment: yes. I agree with Matt K. (+1)

Comment: I suspect it has to do with how FF handles `height: 100%;` on the td. If I change this value I can see the scrollbars, you can start there!

Comment: I think in FF the td is actually much larger than the screen (something to do with the `height: 100%;` as I stated previously), but since the body has `overflow: hidden;` you can't see this effect. anyways, you'll learn a lot more and solve your problem by implementing a proper layout using divs or html5 elements .

Comment: I would have used pure CSS if I could have figured it out.  My original didn't have a header and used CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for absolute positioning.

Always keep your HTML as simple as possible.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div id="leftcol">
            Leftcol
        </div>
        <div id="rightcol">
            main area
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS to set absolute positioning and overflow: auto on your columns.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#leftcol {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 72px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
#rightcol {
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

I set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpsXg/) to view it in the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/hpsXg/

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize I could specify top and bottom to accomplish this